# Push built files to heroku

Tags: git, heroku, gitignore

I need an advice.
How to push `build/www` to heroku.

I have github project and I'd like to push it onto heroku but my build folder is ignored. I do not want to build project directly on heroku cause the devDependencies required.
What is the right solution to work with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it.
Locally I made

```
git add -f build/www
git commit -a -m "some messsage" heroku ...
git reset --hard HEAD~
```

On Jenkins there no step of reset. :)

But still it would be grate to hear if there more convenient way to manage such a situations.